# Is it possible to change language on Qt at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

in my app I need internationalization.
Say I have created several .ts file for different languages e.g.,
German, French, etc. - together with translated phrases.

Now, say the user wants to change the language at run time.
Will it not be possible using Qt approach?

Comment: See http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11708

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a LocaleHandler object in your application and listen to the systemLanguageChanged() signal.

This signal will be called anytime the user changes the language through the settings menu.

When this happens you should update your installed dictionary to the new one with something like the below code:

```
void MyAppSettings::updateLanguage() {
    QString translations = QString("MyApp%1.qm").arg(QLocale().name());
    Application::instance()->removeTranslator(&mTranslator);
    if (mTranslator.load(translations, "app/native/qm")) {
        qDebug() << "LOAD FINISHED";
        Application::instance()->installTranslator(&mTranslator);
    } else {
        qDebug() << "COULD NOT INSTALL TRANSLATIONS " << translations;
    }
}
```

This will remove the current dictionary and replace it with the new one for the chosen system language.

Unfortunately this is not enough, as it will not update any existing screens you have for your app. To update existing strings in QML you should add Retranslate.onLanguageChanged to your translated string.

ex:

```
Label {
    text: qsTrId("header1")  + Retranslate.onLanguageChanged
}
```

This will update the string for the above lavel every time the translator changes. For more information see: [http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*cascades*_qmlretranslate.html](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__qmlretranslate.html)

Comment: For Qt >=5.10 use the simpler [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48719049/5183341) from Musa

Answer (score 9):

The function QQmlEngine::retranslate introduced in Qt 5.10 simply reevaluates all property bindings. This includes all the bindings with a call to qsTr() on the right-hand side.

```
void Settings::switchToLanguage(const QString &language)
{
    if (!m_translator.isEmpty())
        QCoreApplication::removeTranslator(&m_translator);
    m_translator.load(QStringLiteral(":/language_") + language));
    QCoreApplication::installTranslator(&m_translator));
    m_engine->retranslate();
}
```

For more detail you can check [this post](http://www.embeddeduse.com/2017/11/12/new-in-qt-5-10-dynamic-language-change-in-qml/) too.

Comment: what is the `m_engine` object ?

Comment: It's your 'QQmlApplicationEngine'. the application's qml engin that load 'main.qml' file.

Comment: @Nulik you can get m_engine by `QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
`

Comment: What will happen if I don't remove the translator? `QCoreApplication::removeTranslator()`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a [LocaleHandler](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__localehandler.html) and listen for the `onLanguageChanged` signal. When received, re-translate the text e.g. `myLabel->setText(tr("My label"))`.

Comment: or if using ui files UiClass->retranslateUi();

Comment: @KamilKlimek as BB10 uses cascades for UI is your statement true? E.g. BB10 apps must use `bb::cascades::Application` and not `QApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with
[QCoreApplication::installTranslator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#installTranslator)