# QObject::tr() not translating language properly

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

```
QLocale systemLocale;
LOG_ERROR() << "SYSTEM LANGUAGE:" << systemLocale.languageToString(systemLocale.language());
LOG_ERROR() << QObject::tr("Welcome");
```

The second line prints the correct language, when I change the language from the phone settings, however, "Welcome" doesn't get translated to the current system language. What could be the issue with this?

Comment: Do you have this string translated? Did you properly integrate the translations into the build?

Comment: Please see this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355156/is-it-possible-to-change-language-on-qt-at-runtime)

Comment: Can we check which translation file are we currently using?

Answer (score 0):

The translation is probably not loaded. Here's how you can load a file:

```
QTranslator translator;
QString locale_string = QLocale().name();
QString filename = QString("my_app_%1").arg(locale_string);
if (translator.load(filename, "app/native/qm")) {
    app.installTranslator(&translator);
}
```

This would try to load translations from `app/native/qm/my_app_fr.qm` on a french device, for example.

Note that by default, you'll have to restart the application after changing the device language. You can use a [`LocaleHandler`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__localehandler.html) to update the translation when the phone language changes. Listen to [`onSystemLanguageChanged()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__localehandler.html#function-systemlanguagechanged) signal, remove the old translator, then load the new one (same code as above).